wissen vs selbst wissen
I have read/heard the following sentence in https://www.deutsch-perfekt.com/deutsch-hoeren/ein-spezieller-geburtstag :

Das weiß ich doch selbst.

I do not understand the literal translation "I know it myself". Is there any difference in meaning between "Das weiß ich selbst." and "Das weiß ich."?

Just please don't confuse that sentence with "Das weiß selbst ich" ("[It is so simple that] even I know that")

That selbst is a modal particle in that context.

Das weiß ich. — I know that.
Das weiß ich selbst. — I know that, you don't have to tell me.

That doch is another modal particle.

Das weiß ich doch. — I know that, you don't have to tell me.
Das weiß ich doch selbst. — I know that, you don't have to tell me. For real!


I doubt that "selbst" is a modal particle. You would then expect that it cannot be moved, but how about "Selbst weiß er das nicht" ? Also, there is a predication relation with "ich". Perhaps it can even be contrastive: "Das weiß ich selbst und von anderen" - do you get this one?

But in your examples it's not a modal particle any more. It has a contrastive meaning.

"selbst" always has contrastive meaning, in all examples.

Btw., DWDS https://www.dwds.de/wb/selbst#1 calls it a "pronoun".

Doesn't matter because all modal particles are doppelgangers of other words.

(Answer has been completely rewritten from the first version)
You are right to wonder about this example. In general, one would think that the word "selbst" brings in a notion of contrast – between self and others. However, it is remarkable that your example cannot easily be explained by such a contrast alone, so: "Das weiß ich selbst" does not correspond to a contrastive stress on "ich": # "Das weiß ICH" (means something different, e.g. "only I know this, you don't"). Likewise, it does not correspond to "selbst" as emphasis on the self, as in: "Ich selbst weiß das!" (possible, but hard to translate).
Instead, "Das weiß ich selbst" is felt to have a meaning like "you need not tell me" (and it sounds a bit unfriendly). Sometimes a variant can be: "von selbst". Therefore, in the constructions you brought up, it behaves like a causal adverbial, and it refers to the way in which the knowledge comes about.
This is also what the DWDS-entry focuses on, it says that "selbst" means "without help from outside". (https://www.dwds.de/wb/selbst#1)
The other reading that they mention (as selbst#2) is a focusing adverb meaning "even": "Selbst ich weiß das" (even I know this), which is clearly different. Strangely, however, the DWDS fails to distinguish the uses that I've just called emphasis on self ("ich selbst...") from the meaning that corresponds to "von selbst".
This causal meaning of "selbst" is easier to understand if it occurs with action verbs, like "Ich habe das selbst gebaut" (I built it myself). This clearly means: I did it without help from others – but here the verb already refers to the fact that something comes about. So the difficulty with "wissen / know" is that it refers to a pure state, -- nevertheless, "selbst" is able to refer to ways in which the state comes about.
In the end, I think it is still true that "selbst" refers to a contrast between self and others (and this is what unites it with its other uses), but the tricky thing is that this contrastive meaning is combined with a causal meaning.

Doesn't you need not tell me indicate that selbst is a modal particle? Because its meaning is all about the mood in which the remainder is told.

The category "Modalpartikel" in German is not just defined by a meaning. Certain adverbs may have similar meanings but are different in their grammatical properties. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalpartikel#Definition  Compare https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kommentaradverb
